# Omitting a word in conjunctions vs. using "one"

Tags: difference, conjunctions

Which of the following constructions in the conjunctions is read more fluently?

> In Figure 2, **an intact and a damaged grate** are shown.
>
> In Figure 2, **an intact grate and a damaged one** are shown.

Comment: I prefer to say : Figure 2 depicts/shows/... the difference between intact and damaged grates

Comment: Or "...intact and damaged grates are shown."

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence reads smoother to the English speaker's ear.   However, if you are worried that the reader will not understand your exact meaning, I would suggest...

> In Figure 2, an intact grate and a damaged grate are shown.